# How can I translate this SQL query to Django ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT messages1.id, messages1.channel FROM (SELECT * FROM messages WHERE timestamp >= datetime.now() AND channel IN ('ALL', 'UC')) messages1 LEFT JOIN read_messages ON messages1.id = read_messages.message_id WHERE read_messages.id IS NULL;
```

and these are my models:

```py
from django.db import models


class Messages(models.Model):
    channel = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    timestamp = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    publisher = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'messages'


class NotifiedMessages(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.IntegerField()
    message_id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'notified_messages'


class ReadMessages(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    message_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'read_messages'
```

i've tried to use subqueries and other things, but the main problem now is that subquery return an error:
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: subquery must return only one column`

because I was trying to do something like it:

```py
ts = Messages.objects.filter(timestamp__gte=datetime.today(), channel__in=['ALL', 'UC'])
Messages.objects.annotate(messages1=Subquery(ts, output_field=models.CharField()))
```

what is wrong with the code above and what can I do to translate the query correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to use a subquery as an annotation in the wrong way. Subqueries are used to filter a queryset based on values in another queryset.

Here is an example of how to use subqueries.

```
from django.db.models import Q, Subquery, OuterRef

now = datetime.now()

read_message_subquery = ReadMessages.objects.filter(
    user_id=user_id,
    message_id=OuterRef('id')
).values('message_id')

query = Messages.objects.filter(
    timestamp__gte=now,
    channel__in=['ALL', 'UC'],
).exclude(id__in=Subquery(read_message_subquery)).values('id', 'channel')
```